# How to add custom JS to tinymce in wordpress

Tags: plugins, tinymce

So I want to enhance the functionality of the TinyMCE editor in WordPress by adding custom JS script and CSS to it.

I was able to add custom CSS to it by using this method:

```
function plugin_mce_css($stylesheet) {    
    $stylesheet .= ','; 

    $stylesheet .= plugins_url ('editor.css', __FILE__); 

    return $stylesheet;
}
add_action( 'mce_css', 'plugin_mce_css' );
```

Using that, I was able to add some styling to the `wp-editor` css class but when it got to adding custom Js script I wasn't able to do any DOM manipulation of `Wp-editor` after adding JS script with this method:

```
function custom_script() { 
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"></script>',  plugins_url('editor.js', __FILE__) ); 
}
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', 'custom_script' );
```

What am I getting wrong when adding the JS? I need help.

Comment: I'm not very deep into this but as far as I know, you should never use printf to print out scripts in WordPress. In case you want to use inline script tags, you should go for the admin_head hook. Maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

If google search result brought you here see my answer to the exact same question on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77546495/1568334